# Distinguishing between "ed" and "eds" in citation

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, babel, biblatex-chicago

I'm using `biblatex-chicago`, together with `babel` and `csquotes`, as I'm making a compilation with two different languages for the reference section.

It works fine with one exception: cbyeditor is not defined for spanish, for some reason. I can manually define it using

```
\NewBibliographyString{cbyeditor}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{spanish}{cbyeditor = {eds.,}}
```

But this way it won't distinguish between 1 editor (ed.) or 2 or more editors (eds.) How could I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Can you please add an short compilable tex code building your bibliography? Please do not forget to add a used bib entry to your question!

Comment: I don't think `biblatex-chicago` has a Spanish localization. It probably works where it relies on `biblatex`. As for plural forms, there are the cases where they exist, when the roles are specified by functions (editor/editors), but not so in the "by" strings, which are roles expressed as actions. That particular string thus, is to be read as "Editado por", which would be the same for one or more editors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following MWE shows an example use of `cbyeditor`. Note that `cbyeditor` will just come out as **cbyeditor** because `biblatex-chicago` does not have a Spanish localisation file (there is no `cms-spanish.lbx`).

```
\documentclass[spanish]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[notes, backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{aristotle:anima}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Citation: "Aristotle, De Anima, cbyeditor Robert Drew Hicks (Cambridge: Cambridge University Press, 1907)" Bibliography: "Aristotle. De Anima. Editado por Robert Drew Hicks. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press, 1907."]

`cbyeditor` is `biblatex-chicago`'s equivalent of `byeditor` for citations. It usually takes the short form of the string, so for Spanish you probably want

```
\NewBibliographyString{cbyeditor}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{spanish}{
  cbyeditor = {ed\adddotspace por},
}
```

to obtain

> Aristotle, De Anima, ed. por Robert Drew Hicks (Cambridge: Cambridge University Press, 1907)

Note that since the string cleverly uses a passive construction ('editado por'/'edited by'/'herausgegeben von') it avoids the need for a different plural string (at least in all languages `biblatex` currently speaks).

If you really wanted 'ed.'/'eds.' here, you would have to rewrite the entire `byeditor` macro family to use the `editor` strings. I doubt that would be a pleasant experience.

Comment: Is `\NewBibliographyString{cbyeditor}` needed?

Comment: @gusbrs In this case yes because `biblatex-chicago` defines all of its new strings in the `.lbx` files (I think it would be better to define them at one central point in the `.bbx` or `.cbx` where they are needed). Since there is no `cms-spanish.lbx` the string would not be defined otherwise.

Comment: I see, good point. I assumed they were defined in a single place. But I actually forgot, as I went to and fro those `.lbx`s quite a lot in the past.